# change a bash script while it is running

Tags: bash

I have a script `test`

```
#! /bin/bash

sleep 60
echo hello
```

I ran it by setting it executable and `./test`, and while it was running the sleep command, I changed it 
to

```
#! /bin/bash

sleep 60
echo hello!!
```

The output is `hello!!`. I wonder why not `hello`?

How can I make it output `hello` regardless of later change?

Comment: Notice in general, DO NOT modify a running shell script.  As it saves the file position while it is executing the file and thus you could SERIOUSLY affect what is running.  You were lucky in the position you choose to edit the file.

Answer (score 5):

This is the solution that will work for your case.

Break your script into functions, and each time a function is called you `source` it from a separate file.  Then you could edit the files at any time and your running script will pick up the changes next time it gets sourced.

```
foo() {
  source foo.sh
}
foo
```

**Testing**

I have created 2 scripts say `callee.sh` and `called.sh` as below.

```
#The contents of callee.sh script is as below. 
callee.sh

foo() {
  source called.sh
}
foo

#The contents of called.sh script is as below. 
called.sh

#! /bin/bash

sleep 60
echo hello
```

Now, I execute `callee.sh` which in turn calls my `called.sh` script. Basically, `called.sh` is the script which we will be changing dynamically.

Now, when `callee.sh` is getting executed, I open another shell and change the contents as,

```
#! /bin/bash

    sleep 60
    echo hello
    echo "I added more contents here"
```

Now, in the first shell from which I called the script `callee.sh` after the `sleep` is over, the output I get is,

```
hello
```

As you could see, I did not get the `I added more contents here` in my output which is what the desired end result is.

**References**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3399850/1742825